# Setting body ID from includes does not work

Tags: craft3, include

This is my _layouts/main.twig:

```
<body {% if bodyId is defined %}id="{{ bodyId }}"{% endif %}>

  {% include '_layouts/header.twig' %}

  {% block main %}

  {% endblock %}

</body>
```

Then i have blog/_entry.twig with:

```
{% extends '_layouts/main' %}

{% block main %}

{% switch entry.entryType.entryIs.value %}
    {% case 'listing' %}
        {% include 'blog/_listing.twig' %}
    {% case 'listingSimple' %}
        {% include 'blog/_listing-simple.twig' %}
    {% case 'article' %}
        {% include 'blog/_single-entry.twig' %}
{% endswitch %}

{% endblock %}
```

If I do:

```
{% set bodyId = 'article' %}
```

in my blog/_single-entry.twig that does not work.

But it works if i set bodyId in my index.twig in the root that is not a include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I had a similar problem... Had a few things that didn't work for me, but I got it to work. First item: putting the set bodyID inside the `{% block main %}` didn't work for me, it had to be outside of that. Second: it didn't like being a the switch/case format, so I did it as an if-check.

So, try something like this:

```
{% extends '_layouts/main' %}

{% if entry.entryType.entryIs.value == "listing" %}
    {% set bodyId = 'listing' %}
{% elseif entry.entryType.entryIs.value == "listingSimple" %}
    {% set bodyId = 'listing-simple' %}
{% elseif entry.entryType.entryIs.value == "article" %}
    {% set bodyId = 'single-entry' %}
{% endif %}

{% block main %}

{% switch entry.entryType.entryIs.value %}
    {% case 'listing' %}
        {% include 'blog/_listing' %}
    {% case 'listingSimple' %}
        {% include 'blog/_listing-simple' %}
    {% case 'article' %}
        {% include 'blog/_single-entry' %}
{% endswitch %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks that works. I could swear i tried that :-(

Answer (score 2):

So Twig has a particular processing order for things like variables, includes, extends and all that sort of stuff. Basically, you can't set a variable in an included template and then use that in an extended template.

Here's a great article that goes into this topic in a little more depth: https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope - I'd highly recommend you give it a read.